# Android action bar is invisible but still takes up place

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to hide the android action bar, I tried the following in the manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

and also tried the following in my activity's onCreate method:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
getActionBar().hide();  
setContentView(R.layout.viewpager);
```

Both work fine and the actionbar is invisible. But the problem is, I cannot use the space that the actionbar left after it disappeared. I mean, if I want to center a widget in the layout vertically, it counts for the space the action bar covers, and then centers the widget in the space left, and so it looks like not centered.Here is the xml file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_create_db_first_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/data" />
    <TextView 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/textview_create_database"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/create_database"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white_text"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

So can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for `this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either use the no title flag:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Or create your theme and add:

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. I have used similar code in my project. I think the margin:top attribute in your imageview is making it appear below the center.

```
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
```

So remove this line.

Comment: you are right, but i actually had a relativelayout that contained that image and a textview above image, that margin was supposed to set the margin between them. Edited question thanks for the warning